# What are the possible theta roles for to-infinitives in these sentences?

Tags: semantics

For example, in the sentence *I want to sleep.*

The verb *want* takes two arguments, which get two theta roles, *I* gets the agent role, what theta role does *to sleep* get?

Here is another example: *I want her to sleep.*

What theta role does *to sleep* get?

Here is my third and last example, *I want to sleep her*.
What role does *her* get? Is *her* part of the infinitival so does not get assigned any role?

It is important to note that the tags I was able to put on were not even remotely accurate in describing the type of thematic roles I am discussing here in this post. Unfortunately, they they haven't created a tag for theta role theory nor do they allow me to create a new one.

Comment: You asked a similar question here [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/581795/what-is-the-constituent-type-of-laugh-in-i-saw-her-laugh).

Comment: These are catenative constructions. In the first, "want" is a catenative verb, and the infinitival "to sleep" is its catenative complement. In the second, a complex catenative, again "want" is a catenative verb, and the infinitival "to sleep" is its complement. The intervening NP "her" is the syntactic object of the matrix verb "want" and the semantic (_understood_) subject of the subordinate infinitival clause. Note that "her" is a raised object.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you mean the "to sleep" in "I want to sleep" or as in "I want her to sleep"?

Comment: @Bill J You are right. A SIMILAR question, however not the SAME. Nonetheless, my most sincere thanks to you for reiterating the same analysis of the catenative verbs, although my question this time is about what theta roles those infinitival phrases get respectively. But thank you still, I gained more insight into the use of catenative verbs again from your answer.

Comment: Your third and last example, *I want to sleep her*, does not sound felicitous.

Comment: @Bill J I don't know why my last comment reads insincere. I wasn't being snarky in any way shape or form as much as my backtracking words of gratitude may appear.

Comment: I don't really see much future in this "theta" categorisation business anyway - like most of Chomsky's ideas about language, current developments in neural net natural language processing tend to imply such things are a waste of time. But if "theta type **goal**" works for you with *I want [me] **to sleep***, I don't see why the same category shouldn't apply to *I want **her** to sleep*. Unless you want to sub-categorise theta type **goal** for things like "Agent-enacted" (reflexive?) and "Patient-enacted" (indirect object?).

Comment: Tricky; 'goal' seems usually to be reserved for truly directional cases (Paris; the station ...).

Comment: Consider: *I don't want him calling me a slacker afterwards.*

Answer (score 1):

Theta roles only apply to noun phrases, not to all verbal arguments. The phrase *to sleep* is not a noun phrase, so it doesn't have a theta role. (In some theoretical frameworks, that clause contains a "null subject" called PRO, which can be assigned a theta role; its theta role would then be the same as that of *her* in the next sentence.)

In your second sentence *I want her to sleep*, the theta role of *her* would probably be described as Experiencer, since she is the one "experiencing" sleep. That said, linguists who work in a theta-role framework don't all use the same list of theta roles, and there can be disagreements about how best to classify specific instances.

Your third example, *I want to sleep her*, is not a grammatical English sentence, so it can't really be analyzed.

Comment: THANK YOU! PRO, that empty category pronoun is the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Yes ... I'm glad there's disagreement. Here, 'her/[referent]' is also the desiree. The lady has two notional roles.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth She isn't a desiree -- *I want her to sleep* doesn't entail *I want her*, just like *I believe you to be lying* doesn't entail *I believe you*.